# Use GMT+4 time in this countdown script no matter what GMT is the visitor

Tags: javascript, countdown

This countdown time script works fine but is different for all GMT of visitors. I would like a global time GMT+4 for everyone, doesn't matter what country is the visitor from , the time should be global

What i would need to add so my script reads only general time and where i need to place it?

I would appreciate if someone can edit my script and include this function inside

Thank you in advance

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
var events = new Array();

events[1]={name: 'Blood Castle:', startUp: new Array(
    {hour:0,minute:25},
    {hour:2,minute:25},
    {hour:4,minute:25},
    {hour:6,minute:25},
    {hour:8,minute:25},
    {hour:10,minute:25},
    {hour:12,minute:25},
    {hour:14,minute:25},
    {hour:16,minute:25},
    {hour:18,minute:25},
    {hour:20,minute:25},
    {hour:22,minute:25}
)}

events[2]={name: 'Devil Square:', startUp: new Array(
    {hour:1,minute:55},
    {hour:3,minute:55},
    {hour:5,minute:55},
    {hour:7,minute:55},
    {hour:9,minute:55},
    {hour:11,minute:55},
    {hour:13,minute:55},
    {hour:15,minute:55},
    {hour:17,minute:55},
    {hour:19,minute:55},
    {hour:21,minute:55},
    {hour:23,minute:55}
)}

events[3]={name: 'Chaos Castle:', startUp: new Array(
    {hour:0,minute:55},
    {hour:2,minute:55},
    {hour:4,minute:55},
    {hour:6,minute:55},
    {hour:8,minute:55},
    {hour:10,minute:55},
    {hour:12,minute:55},
    {hour:14,minute:55},
    {hour:16,minute:55},
    {hour:18,minute:55},
    {hour:20,minute:55},
    {hour:22,minute:55}
)}

events[4]={name: 'Red Dragon:', startUp: new Array(
    {hour:0,minute:0},
    {hour:2,minute:0},
    {hour:4,minute:0},
    {hour:6,minute:0},
    {hour:8,minute:0},
    {hour:10,minute:0},
    {hour:12,minute:0},
    {hour:14,minute:0},
    {hour:16,minute:0},
    {hour:18,minute:0},
    {hour:20,minute:0},
    {hour:22,minute:0}
)}

events[5]={name: 'Gold Invasion:', startUp: new Array(
    {hour:0,minute:0},
    {hour:2,minute:0},
    {hour:4,minute:0},
    {hour:6,minute:0},
    {hour:8,minute:0},
    {hour:10,minute:0},
    {hour:12,minute:0},
    {hour:14,minute:0},
    {hour:16,minute:0},
    {hour:18,minute:0},
    {hour:20,minute:0},
    {hour:22,minute:0}
)}

events[6]={name: 'White Wizard:', startUp: new Array(
    {hour:0,minute:0},
    {hour:2,minute:0},
    {hour:4,minute:0},
    {hour:6,minute:0},
    {hour:8,minute:0},
    {hour:10,minute:0},
    {hour:12,minute:0},
    {hour:14,minute:0},
    {hour:16,minute:0},
    {hour:18,minute:0},
    {hour:20,minute:0},
    {hour:22,minute:0}
)}

events[7]={name: 'Blue:', startUp: new Array(
    {hour:0,minute:40},
    {hour:1,minute:40},
    {hour:2,minute:40},
    {hour:3,minute:40},
    {hour:4,minute:40},
    {hour:5,minute:40},
    {hour:6,minute:40},
    {hour:7,minute:40},
    {hour:8,minute:40},
    {hour:9,minute:40},
    {hour:10,minute:40},
    {hour:11,minute:40},
    {hour:12,minute:40},
    {hour:13,minute:40},
    {hour:14,minute:40},
    {hour:15,minute:40},
    {hour:16,minute:40},
    {hour:17,minute:40},
    {hour:18,minute:40},
    {hour:19,minute:40},
    {hour:20,minute:40},
    {hour:21,minute:40},
    {hour:22,minute:40},
    {hour:23,minute:40},
    {hour:24,minute:40}
)}

events[7]={name: 'Hide&Seek:', startUp: new Array(
    {hour:0,minute:42},
    {hour:1,minute:22},
    {hour:2,minute:32},
    {hour:3,minute:42},
    {hour:4,minute:52},
    {hour:6,minute:02},
    {hour:7,minute:12},
    {hour:8,minute:22},
    {hour:9,minute:32},
    {hour:10,minute:42},
    {hour:11,minute:52},
    {hour:13,minute:02},
    {hour:14,minute:12},
    {hour:15,minute:22},
    {hour:16,minute:32},
    {hour:17,minute:42},
    {hour:18,minute:52},
    {hour:20,minute:02},
    {hour:21,minute:12},
    {hour:22,minute:22},
    {hour:23,minute:32}
)}

events[8]={name: 'Sky:', startUp: new Array(
    {hour:1,minute:5},
    {hour:4,minute:5},
    {hour:7,minute:5},
    {hour:10,minute:5},
    {hour:13,minute:5},
    {hour:16,minute:5},
    {hour:19,minute:5},
    {hour:23,minute:5}
)}

events[9]={name: 'Boss Attack:', startUp: new Array(
    {hour:1,minute:50},
    {hour:4,minute:50},
    {hour:7,minute:50},
    {hour:10,minute:50},
    {hour:13,minute:50},
    {hour:16,minute:50},
    {hour:23,minute:50}
)}


events[10]={name: 'Happy Hour:', startUp: new Array(
    {hour:5,minute:5},
    {hour:2,minute:5},
    {hour:8,minute:5},
    {hour:11,minute:5},
    {hour:14,minute:5},
    {hour:17,minute:5},
    {hour:20,minute:5},
    {hour:0,minute:5}
)}

events[11]={name: 'Hit and Up:', startUp: new Array(
    {hour:0,minute:20},
    {hour:2,minute:20},
    {hour:5,minute:20},
    {hour:8,minute:20},
    {hour:11,minute:20},
    {hour:14,minute:20},
    {hour:20,minute:20}
)}

events[12]={name: 'Raklion:', startUp: new Array(
    {hour:0,minute:15},
    {hour:3,minute:15},
    {hour:6,minute:15},
    {hour:9,minute:15},
    {hour:12,minute:15},
    {hour:15,minute:15},
    {hour:18,minute:15},
    {hour:21,minute:15}
)}

events[13]={name: 'Moss:', startUp: new Array(
    {hour:3,minute:35},
    {hour:7,minute:35},
    {hour:11,minute:35},
    {hour:15,minute:35},
    {hour:19,minute:35},
    {hour:23,minute:35}
)}

events[14]={name: 'Illusion Temple:', startUp: new Array(
    {hour:0,minute:25},
    {hour:1,minute:25},
    {hour:2,minute:25},
    {hour:3,minute:25},
    {hour:4,minute:25},
    {hour:5,minute:25},
    {hour:6,minute:25},
    {hour:7,minute:25},
    {hour:8,minute:25},
    {hour:9,minute:25},
    {hour:10,minute:25},
    {hour:11,minute:25},
    {hour:12,minute:25},
    {hour:13,minute:25},
    {hour:14,minute:25},
    {hour:15,minute:25},
    {hour:16,minute:25},
    {hour:17,minute:25},
    {hour:18,minute:25},
    {hour:19,minute:25},
    {hour:20,minute:25},
    {hour:21,minute:25},
    {hour:22,minute:25},
    {hour:23,minute:25},
    {hour:24,minute:25}
)}

events[15]={name: 'Castle Deep:', startUp: new Array(
    {hour:1,minute:25},
    {hour:7,minute:25},
    {hour:13,minute:25},
    {hour:19,minute:25}
)}

events[16]={name: 'CryWolf:', startUp: new Array(
    {hour:1,minute:45},
    {hour:4,minute:45},
    {hour:7,minute:45},
    {hour:10,minute:45},
    {hour:13,minute:45},
    {hour:16,minute:20},
    {hour:19,minute:45},
    {hour:22,minute:45}
)}

var curTime=1336998502;
var dateTime=1336953600;
if(localStorage.curTime) {
    curTime = Number(localStorage.curTime);
} else {
    // use default set above
}
// not sure if we need to persist dateTime but doing it anyway!
if(localStorage.dateTime) {
    dateTime = Number(localStorage.dateTime);
} else {
    // use default set above
}
function timeLeft(i){
    for(j in events[i].startUp){
        tmp=events[i].startUp[j].hour*3600+events[i].startUp[j].minute*60
        if(dateTime+tmp>curTime){
            return dateTime+tmp-curTime;
        }
    }
    tmp=events[i].startUp[0].hour*3600+events[i].startUp[0].minute*60
    return dateTime+86400+tmp-curTime;
}

function getFormatedLeftTime($seconds){
    $second = $seconds % 60;
    $minutes = parseInt(($seconds / 60) % 60);
    $hour =  parseInt(($seconds / 3600) % 24);
    $days = parseInt($seconds / (24 * 3600));

    $ret = '';
    if ($days > 0)
        if ($days == 1) $ret += '1 day ';
        else $ret += $days + ' days ';


    if ($hour > 0){
        if ($hour < 10) $hour = '0' + $hour;
        $ret += $hour + ':';
    }else if ($days > 0) $ret += '00:';

    if($minutes < 10) $minutes = '0' + $minutes;

    $ret += $minutes + ':';

    if ($second < 10) $second = '0' + $second;

    $ret += $second;
    return $ret;

}

function updateTimes(){
    curTime++;
    localStorage.curTime = curTime; // save current time
    for (i in events){
        document.getElementById("timeLeft"+i).innerHTML=getFormatedLeftTime(timeLeft(i));
    }
}

for(i in events)
    document.getElementById("eventList").innerHTML+="<div style='float:right; color: #FFFF00;' id='timeLeft"+i+"'>"+getFormatedLeftTime(timeLeft(i))+"</div><div style=\"color: #00FFFF;\"><strong>"+events[i].name+"</strong></div>";
setInterval("updateTimes()", 1000);



</script>
```

Comment: well, considering Javascript is a client side langauge, its always going to use the local time.  If you want a standard time across all users and locations, you will need to pass it down from your server side code.

Answer (score 1):

If you only *ever* deal in the *milliseconds-since-epoch* format of time, you shouldn't need to worry about the timezones.

So, on the *server* side, calculate the correct finish time in milliseconds, and then have that sent to the client when they download the script.

On the client side you then only need to work out the *difference* between the server supplied time, and the client's epoch, and convert that different into hours, minutes, seconds, etc.

Comment: cant this script have a function that calls a certain global time only to use?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript dates have a method called [`getTimezoneOffset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) which returns the offset from GMT in minutes.  You can use this value to coordinate to a "central" timezone:

```javascript
var d = new Date();
d.toString(); // Mon May 14 2012 13:20:24 GMT-0600 (MDT)
d.getTimezoneOffset(); // => 360 (GMT-600)
var localTimeOffsetHours = d.getTimezoneOffset() / 60; // => 6
```

Comment: added this lines in my script but can't see any changes, time is still different

Comment: @Xander: these lines don't do anything by themselves except show you how to get the timezone offset in minutes and hours.  You must *apply* this offset to the local time in your script to have any effect, e.g. try using `d.setHours(d.getHours() + localTimeOffsetHours)`.

Comment: i m really begginer so i don't even know where to add this inside the script. Someone was telling about the server side. If i create a .js file with this script, how can put the time on website for clients from that server side .js file script?

Comment: @Xander: sorry, you'll need to add more information to your question.

Comment: If i save the script i copy pasted in my question as a .js file so will be server side can the time remain the same for everyone no matter what GMT the visitor has?.  How can i load each value for each event listed there in a html page? For example Blood Castle: timexxx, Devil Square: timeyyy and so on. Timers are already seted inside the script as you can see. I want all this to be displayed on website but i want to be same for everyone, to be server time (same GMT for all)